# OnClick event in WinForms DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, buttonclick

I am using DataGridView in WinForms and by this piece of code I am assigning it columns and values

```
dataGrid.DataSource = sourceObject;
```

only by this line all the columns and values into the grid. 
How do I handle the onClick event of a specific row or field. I want to do edit a particular item in the grid but I cannot find any way to send the id of an item from the event method.

There is class DataGridViewEventHandler which I do not understand?

I have also tried to add columns manually as a buttons but I did not find way to assign it action method onClick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot find **"OnClick"** event for cell inside DataGridView, as it does not exist. Have a look at MSDN Page for  [DataGridView Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_events.aspx) provided  for Cell Manipulation and Events

Here are some samples from MSDN, about the events which you may use

**Sample CellMouseClick Event and Handler**

```
   private void DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)    {

    System.Text.StringBuilder cellInformation = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    cellInformation .AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "ColumnIndex", e.ColumnIndex );
    cellInformation .AppendLine();
    cellInformation .AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "RowIndex", e.RowIndex );
    cellInformation .AppendLine();
    MessageBox.Show(cellInformation.ToString(), "CellMouseClick Event" );
}
```

**Sample CellClick Event and Handler**

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

    if (turn.Text.Equals(gameOverString)) { return; }

    DataGridViewImageCell cell = (DataGridViewImageCell)
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

    if (cell.Value == Play)
    {
        // PlaySomething()
    }
    else if (cell.Value == Sing)
    {
        // SingSomeThing();
    }
    else 
    {
     MessagBox.Show("Please Choose Another Value");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

[`Here`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_events.aspx), you can see a list of events for the DataGridView. If you want to see if a cell has been clicked, you would want to consume the [`CellMouseclick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmouseclick.aspx) event. In your code, you can handle the event like this:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    //Do something

}
```

To get specific details about the cell, then you can use the 'e' property mentioned above. It's of type [`DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellmouseeventargs.aspx). This will give you information about that specific cell. You can handle most of the other events, found in the first link, in the same way. (Not all the events will have `DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs` as the argument, of course).

Comment: Thanks
 Here in your method only source of information is               DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e that is passed in. But I still cannot get value from the cell in order to preform some operations.

Comment: Hi, check the example at the bottom of this page:
`http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick.aspx` . It shows an example of how to get the value of the cell.